# How to test http api that uses csurf csrf protection with mocha/chai?

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, csrf, chai, chai-http

Not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787601/nodejs-express-application-testing-how-to-submit-csrf-token-when-testing-with)

I want to know what are the minimum headers/cookies needed to set in order to test an api that uses csurf csrf protection.

In my server I have:

```
const app = express()

const csrfMiddleware = csurf({
    cookie: true
})

app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(csrfMiddleware)
app.get('/singup', ...)
app.post('/singup', ...)
```

In the test file:

```
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const request = chai.request;
const expect = chai.expect;

const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const app = "http://localhost:3000" 

function extractCsrfToken(res) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(res.text);
    return $('[name=_csrf]').val();
   }

describe('Post Endpoints', () => {
  it('should create a new user', () => {
        request(app).get('/singup').end((err, resGet)=>{
          expect(err).to.be.null;
          expect(resGet).to.have.status(200)
          const _csrf = extractCsrfToken(resGet);

          console.log(`sending request with csrf token ${_csrf}`)
          request(app)
          .post('/singup')
          .set('Cookie', `_csrf=${_csrf}`)
          .set('Connection', 'keep-alive')
          .set('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8')
          .send({
              username: "teste-automatizado",
              email: 'some-email@example.com',
              password: '12345678',
              passwordConfirm: '12345678'
      
          }).end((err2, res)=>{
            expect(err2).to.be.null;
            expect(res).to.have.status(200)
          })
          
        })   
  })
})
```

What I expect is the user to be created and a 200 return from the POST request which is not happening because it's failing with 403 from the middleware:

```
$ npm test

> app@1.0.0 test
> mocha



  Post Endpoints
    ✔ should create a new user


  1 passing (21ms)

sending request with csrf token PDwitHYN-ttgB5zAIGCQqq9cCxgwkbXyyrMM

/home/fabio/src/project/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:962
    throw err;
    ^
AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 403
    at /home/fabio/src/project/test.js:37:33
    at Test.Request.callback (/home/fabio/src/project/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:716:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/fabio/src/project/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:916:18)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  showDiff: true,
  actual: 403,
  expected: 200
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/csurf.html), the token is expected to be in a header named `CSRF-Token`.

```js
request(app)
  .post('/singup')
  .set('CSRF-Token', _csrf)
...
```

Additionally, you probably need to set a [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header on your request. But you should use the value of the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header from the response of your first request.

For that, chai has options to [retain the cookies](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http#retaining-cookies-with-each-request). The key is to use an agent to make all requests.

```js
const agent = chai.request.agent(app)

agent.get('/singup').end((err, res) => {
  // do some tests and get the token
  // ...
  // the agent will use the cookie from the previous request
  // so you only need to set the CSRF-Token header 
  agent.post('/singup')
    .set('CSRF-Token', _csrf)
    .send({ username: 'me', password: '123' })
    .end((err, res) => {
       // handle the post response 
    })
})

agent.close()
```